# Definition of yarn queue capacity

Tags: hadoop-yarn

If I search for a generic definition of "capacity", Oxford languages says, "the maximum amount that something can contain".  If I ask yarn for the status of the default queue, I get the following (less relevant information omitted):

```
> yarn queue -status default
...
Queue Information :
Queue Name : default
        State : RUNNING
        Capacity : 100.0%
        Current Capacity : .0%
        Maximum Capacity : 100.0%
```

I hate to sound pedantic, but if capacity is the "maximum amount", what is "Maximum Capacity" and how does that compare to "Capacity"?  Does "Current Capacity" of zero indicate that there is no room left in the queue?  I think so, but one of my coworkers thinks it means the opposite, that all of the room is still available.  And really shouldn't capacity be some kind of measurable unit, not a percentage?

I haven't been able to find yarn's definition of these terms.  I'm hoping somebody here can explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best information I have found so far, from a Cloudera blog on [YARN Capacity and Hierarchical Design](https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/).

> Queues are laid out in a hierarchical design with the topmost parent
> being the ‘root’ of the cluster queues, from here leaf (child) queues
> can be assigned from the root, or branches which can have leafs on
> themselves.  Capacity is assigned to these queues as min and max
> percentages of the parent in the hierarchy. The **minimum capacity** is
> the amount of resources the queue should expect to have available to
> it if everything is running maxed out on the cluster. The **maximum**
> **capacity** is an elastic like capacity that allows queues to make use of
> resources which are not being used to fill minimum capacity demand in
> other queues.